# How to write regex to find one directory in a URL?

Tags: php, regex

Here is the subject:

```
http://www.mysite.com/files/get/937IPiztQG/the-blah-blah-text-i-dont-need.mov
```

What I need using regex is only the bit before the last / (including that last / too)
The 937IPiztQG string may change; it will contain `a-z A-Z 0-9 - _`

Here's what I tried:

```
$code = strstr($url, '/http:\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/files\/get\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)./');
```

---

**EDIT:** I need to use regex because I don't actually know the URL.  I have string like this...

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/files/get/1B-MenlPW0/my-file.doc">a song</a>
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/files/get/1ZeR5KEo9x/my-song.mp3">more text</a>
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/files/get/8IySvO5gMD/my-video.avi">oh and here goes some more blah blah</a>
```

I need it to read that string and cut off filename part of the URLs.

Comment: Never mind I found the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really don't need a regexp here. Here is a simple solution:

```
echo basename(dirname('http://www.mysite.com/files/get/937IPiztQG/the-blah-blah-text-i-dont-need.mov'));
// echoes "937IPiztQG"
```

Also, I'd like to quote Jamie Zawinski:

> "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."

Comment: +1 for a good answer, -1 for the over(ab)used JZ quote. I'm just so sick of hearing that quote.

Answer (score 2):

This seems far too simple to use regex. Use something similar to [strrpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) to look for the last occurrence of the '/' character, and then use [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to trim the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
/http:\/\/www.mysite.com\/files\/get\/([^/]+)\/
```

How about something like this? Which should capture anything that's not a /, 1 or more times before a /.

Answer (score 0):

The strstr() function does not use a regular expression for any of its arguments *it's the wrong function for regex replacement*.

Are you thinking of preg_replace()?

But a function like [basename()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) would be more appropriate.

Comment: Im not looking to replace it with anything, I need to get that url using $code

Comment: Ok, but my point was that strstr doesn't understand regexes, preg_replace (or preg_match) *do* but simply extracting the filename or folder name is a job for another function. Perhaps I should have suggested dirname()

Answer (score 0):

The greediness of regexp will assure this works fine `^.*/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ok=preg_match('#mysite\.com/files/get/([^/]*)#i',$url,$m);
if($ok) $code=$m[1];
```

Then give a good read to these pages

- http://www.php.net/preg_match
- preg_replace

Note

- the use of "#" as a delimiter to avoid getting trapped into escaping too many "/"
- the "i" flag making match insensitive
  (allowing more liberal spellings of the MySite.com domain name)
- the $m array of captured results

Comment: This only get finds matches on links how i desire them to be.
I need a script that actually changes those links inside the string to how i desire

Comment: hence something like
$url=preg_replace('#http://www\.mysite\.com/files/get/([^/]*)[^"]*#i','smtg \1 smtg',$url);