# How to use preg_replace correct in the following case?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I hope somebody could help me out with some „preg_replace“ skills.

I have the following URL:
http://www.domain.com/goto/test-string/

Now I just want to get the „test-string“ part of the URL.
Any idea how I can solve this with preg_replace?

Thanks in advance already!!!

Best,
Florian

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write regex to find one directory in a URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515031/how-to-write-regex-to-find-one-directory-in-a-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `preg_match()` would be a better tool for you:

```
if (preg_match('/([^/]*)/$', $url, $m) {
    echo "The string you are looking for is $m[1]<br />\n";
}
```

but since you specifically asked for `preg_replace()` I suppose you could do something like this:

```
$foo = preg_replace('/^.*?/([^/]*)/$/', '$1', $url);
```

EDIT: I had forgotten to escape my slashes within the regex. Easier to just replace the regex delineators with pipe-symbols so that slashes are no longer special.

```
$foo = preg_replace('|^.*?/([^/]*)/$|', '$1', $url);
```

Comment: Hello Peter, the '$foo = preg_replace('/^.*?/([^/]*)/$', '$1', $url);' looked very promising. But it is returning an empty "result" and not the "test-string" value. Any idea why??

Comment: Apologies. I used the slash character at the start and end of my regex and then also put unescaped slashes within the regex. I have updated it above by using different characters to start/end the regex.

Comment: YEAH! This worked! Thank you very much Peter! Higly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `parse_url()` to get the pieces:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Then using `explode( '/', $sUrl );` to get the string as needed.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

For dynamic parsing you may need to tweak some more.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this one..

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/goto/test-string/hi/';

preg_match('/.*\/(.*?)\//',$url,$match);
echo $match[1];
```